# Adding variables and output to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I am using Bootstrap buttons set with data-toggle="button" that toggles the active class on the button so I figured I would use hasClass to update the variables. As you can tell I am new to javascript/jquery. I then push the variables out to html and want it to update based on the buttons being selected or de-selected, I just can't quite what method I should use. Is AJAX necessary?

Snippet:

```js
var priceA = 300;
var priceB = 400;
var imgBtn = 0;
var mscBtn = 0;
var outputPrice = priceA + imgBtn + mscBtn;

$('#showPrice').html(outputPrice);

$('.priceTable button').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');

  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    imgBtn = 25;
  } else {
    imgBtn = 0;
  }

  $('#showPrice').html(outputPrice);

});
```

```css
.active {background-color:red;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 id="showPrice"></h2>

<table class="priceTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg priceButton imageBtn" id="imageBtn">Image Gallery</button>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg priceButton" id="musicBtn" role="button" aria-pressed="false">Music Player</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `click()` and `hasClass()` to check and trigger your variable updates

Something like this:

```
$('#imageBtn').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")){
         imgBtn = 25;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I am sure there is a much easier way but this is what I was able to figure out and it works. Any improvement suggestions would be appreciated as I use them as a learning experience.

Here is jquery that includes additional buttons. When a button is selected, it adds that to the price range of priceA and priceB. When deselected, it reduces it again from the price range.

```
    var priceA = 300;
    var priceB = 400;
    var imgBtn = 0;
    var mscBtn = 0;
    var vidBtn = 0;
    var strBtn = 0;
    var blgBtn = 0;
    var othBtn = 0;

    $('#showPrice, #showPrice2').html('$' + priceA + ' - ' + '$' + priceB);


    $('.priceTable button').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    if($('.imageBtn').hasClass('active')) {
        imgBtn = 25;
    } else {imgBtn = 0;}

    if($('.musicBtn').hasClass('active')) {
        mscBtn = 50;
    } else {mscBtn = 0;}

    if($('.videoBtn').hasClass('active')) {
        vidBtn = 50;
    } else {vidBtn = 0;}

    if($('.storeBtn').hasClass('active')) {
        strBtn = 75;
    } else {strBtn = 0;}

    if($('.blogBtn').hasClass('active')) {
        blgBtn = 75;
    } else {blgBtn = 0;}

    if($('.otherBtn').hasClass('active')) {
        othBtn = 75;
    } else {othBtn = 0;}

                        });

function calcPrice (){
    var outputPriceA = priceA + imgBtn + mscBtn + vidBtn + strBtn + blgBtn + othBtn;
    var outputPriceB = priceB + imgBtn + mscBtn + vidBtn + strBtn + blgBtn + othBtn;
    $('#showPrice, #showPrice2').html('$' + outputPriceA + ' - ' + '$' + outputPriceB);
};
```